# How to force Super+E shortcut to show computer drives?

Tags: windows, windows-10, shortcuts

In Windows 10, Microsoft changed the Super+E shortcut to open "Quick accesses" window. Is there any config to make it similar the presvious versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Explorer and go to `View -> Options -> General`

Change the setting **Open File Explorer** from `Quick Access` to `This PC`

[image]